# Telegram group joining links are not responding (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: telegram, telegram-group

This problem has been happening for quite some time. I tried contacting telegram customer support over this issue but unfortunately haven't heard back from them since.

Whenever I try to click on any Telegram group joining hyperlink, it just keeps on buffering and shows a "took too long to respond" kind of error. This is not something that was happening earlier. I then have to somehow transfer this link to join from my mobile device. That is the only solution that I'm aware of for this issue.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'd certainly love to know about a more permanent solution rather than the rather sloppy mobile workaround that I use currently. Anything that would aid me in opening the links in Laptop/Desktop devices itself, would be a huge plus.
(An associated screenshot is also attached)

[image]